# Importing LTSpice Library or Component model from Github

Tags: ltspice, library, import

Instead of having my library on my machine which runs LTSpice, I want to put them on the cloud, something like Github, where I save all my library components, models and symbols and import them to my LTspice where ever I am and share them with others. LTspice has .inc and .lib directives to import models from a URL, for example:
.inc http://www.company.com/models/library.lib

I tried to include the following but did not work ... How to make it work ?
.inc https://github.com/wissa/LTSpice/blob/main/MyLib/Diodes/1N4001.lib

LTSpice says

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is twofold:

1. the link must take you to the file directly, not a web page. So the raw file link of githib is needed like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wissa/LTSpice/main/MyLib/Diodes/1N4001.txt
2. LTSpice doesn't like https or doesn't like being behind a https proxy (not sure about that) so this works in my case: http://raw.githubusercontent.com/wissa/LTSpice/main/MyLib/Diodes/1N4001.txt

Answer (score 2):

An alternative here is to use git to manage your files. I won't get into how to use git here.

You will then have a local copy of all your files, backed up and under version control in the cloud (github).